# How to Import MarkLogic one file many documents with content Pump

Tags: marklogic, mlcp

I have a correctly formatted single json file which is an array of documents ( about 60,000 ). I can import it using node api, but just wondering how I would import this file using the Marklogic content pump ( windows ).

I tried using basic options and it just creates one document called orders.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For MLCP, a properly formatted JSON aggregate(Called Line-delimited JSON) file is *not* an array of objects. It is a file with one stringified object *per line*. Think CSV, but JSON stuff instead.

Imagine if you passed an array - the MLCP process would have to parse the entire file into a JSON array to process. One object per line means that MLCP can easily shard the file and process in parallel. In fact, I do not think it even parses to JSON if you use automatic URIs.

Bad:

```
[
  {
    "bar": "baz"
  },
  {
    "bar": "buz"
  }
]
```

Good:

```
{"bar":"baz"}
{"bar":"buz"}
```

All the goodies about this can be found here:
[MLCP User Guide](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mlcp.pdf)

**Relevant section are:**
(Accurate for document version: '9.0-3, September, 2017')

- 4.10
- 4.10.1